# Power BI Measure

Tags: powerbi-desktop

I cant figure out the issue why my Measure query is not able to fetch data.

Let me Explain The Data Structure.
My Data Table, Contains several columns but specially mentioning 3 column names because I want my query to fetch data from these columns based on the slicer selection.

Vacation Status N
Vacation Status N2
Vacation Status N3

```
{   
Test Date = 
IF([SelectedFdate]="Vacation Status N",CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(Data),Data[Branch]="Al Ain OPS",Data[Vacation Status N]="OnDuty")+0,
IF([SelectedFdate]="Vacation Status N2",CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(Data),Data[Branch]="Al Ain OPS",Data[Vacation Status N2]="OnDuty")+0,
if([SelectedFdate]="Vacation Status N3",CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(Data),Data[Branch]="Al Ain OPS",Data[Vacation Status N3]="OnDuty")+0,0)))
}
```

`SelectedFdate` is the measure of selected value of a slicer and then I used this value to compare and fetch the data accordingly.

But my measure works well only if SelectedFdate = Vacation Status N, and it shows zero results for other selections.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Edit your question and add definition for [SelectedFdate]; show example of data and describe how you use this new measure.

Answer (score 0):

SelectedFdate fetch the data from the data based on the slicer selection.
Slicer downdown is list of 3 items
Today
+1 Day
+2 Day

below is the table from where measure [SelectedFdate] fetches the result

{`SelectedFdate = SELECTEDVALUE('Selected Date'[FVType],"No Selection")`}